# Which type of quantization is better?

Tags: quantization, nonuniform

If a signal's amplitude has a uniform PDF, which is better in the sense of producing a smaller quantization error: optimal scalar quantization or quantization with compressor (non-uniform quantization)?

Comment: It depends on your application and the dynamics of the signal you're trying to quantize. There is no general answer.

Comment: What if the  quantization with compressor is  with µ-law algorithm ?

Comment: @MBaz what about this case ?

Comment: That quantizer is optimized for voice signals.

Comment: normally, if the p.d.f. of the signal is uniform, then a uniform quantization error is the best you can hope for (ignoring time-dependent knowledge like what is assumed with Linear Predictive Coding).  if the p.d.f. of the signal is not uniform, then, given the same number of quantized values (*"words"* or *"symbols"*), then it is better to trade larger quantization steps for the less probable values to get smaller quantization steps (and error) for the more probable values.  Rabiner and Schaefer deal with this in *Digital Processing of Speech Signals*.